# Connecting two sockets in different networks in python

Tags: python

For a while, I've been trying to connect my computer to another one in another network using sockets, as I already know how to do this with two computers in the same network.

I already opened a port in my private IP address. Knowing my private and public IP and the port that is open, how can I connect a socket to that port? Being the computer whose private IP has an open port the server.

Comment: Actually this is not python related question. In python you can simply use `socket` module and you connect to a server using `server_address = (ip, port) 
sock.connect(server_address)`. But you have to ensure that this adress and port is reachable from client computer, probably by defining apropriate firewall rules on server or on server network gateway. So I would suggest asking how to do that on superuser.com

Comment: it can be very broad problem.

Comment: @running.t but the problem I have is that the port I opened is in my private IP address, and I don't know how to access that port from an outside network.

Comment: @marlasca23: Exactly, that's why you should set appropriate firewall rule on your gateway to enable connections from outside your private network to machine in private zone. You can do that for example using port forwarding rules on your router. And that is why I think you should ask how to do that on other page, i.e [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com).